# Preventing saving duplicate values in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm attempting to use this method below to save or create a `GameMO` object which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. The problem is that when I call my `winnerChanged()` method below when I change a `UISegmentedControl`'s selected value, I call this `saveOrCreateGameMO()` method below and that ends up creating a new GameMO object stored in CoreData instead of loading up the one already in CoreData and just updating it. I can't figure out why this is happening. Here's what I see in the logs when I change the winner of a game:

```
Saving game because winner was changed
Updating Game to CoreData
```

This tells me that the game is trying to update an already existing GameMO object because the `NSPredicate` in the `FetchRequest` is evaluating to true and is finding at least one game in CoreData with the same `id` (just a random UUID string) and is using that instead of creating a new one.

Even more confusing, the first time I run my app (after removing it from the simulator entirely to reset CoreData's persistent store) it spits out `Updating Conference to CoreData` and `Updating Team to CoreData` from `saveOrCreateConference()` and `saveOrCreateTeam()` respectively, indicating that it's already somehow found a valid value for the NSPredicate like `NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", teamMO.name)`. How is this possible, if the persistent store is cleared? I've also included how I'm loading games below.

```swift
@IBAction func winnerChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        os_log("Saving game because winner was changed", type: .debug)
        let viewcell = sender.superview?.superview as? ConferenceGamesTableViewCell
        guard viewcell != nil else {
            os_log("viewcell is nil in winnerChanged in ConferenceGamesTableViewController", type: .debug)
            return
        }
        guard let game = viewcell?.game else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap game in winnerChanged in ConferenceGamesTableViewController", type: .debug)
            return
        }
        guard let winnerName = sender.titleForSegment(at: sender.selectedSegmentIndex) else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap game winner from UISegmentedControl in ConferenceGamesTableViewController", type: .debug)
            return
        }
        guard let winnerConferenceName = Conference.name(forTeamName: winnerName) else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap game winner conference name in ConferenceGamesTableViewController", type: .debug)
            return
        }
        game.winner = Team(teamName: winnerName, conferenceName: winnerConferenceName)
        guard let gameMO = GameMO.newGameMO(fromGame: game) else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap gameMO from game in ConferenceGamesTableViewController", type: .debug)
            return
        }

        let dataModelManager = DataModelManager.shared
        dataModelManager.saveOrCreateGameMO(gameMO: gameMO)
    }
```

```swift
public func saveOrCreateGameMO(gameMO: GameMO) {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "GameMO")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", gameMO.id)

        do {
            let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

            let objectUpdate = test[0] as! GameMO
            objectUpdate.setValue(gameMO.id, forKey: "id")
            objectUpdate.setValue(gameMO.conferencesNames, forKeyPath: "conferencesNames")
            objectUpdate.setValue(gameMO.confidence, forKeyPath: "confidence")
            objectUpdate.setValue(gameMO.contestantsNames, forKeyPath: "contestantsNames")
            objectUpdate.setValue(gameMO.winnerName, forKeyPath: "winnerName")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                os_log("Updating Game to CoreData", type: .debug)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not update game to CoreData. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        } catch {
            os_log("Could not fetch game from CoreData. Saving it as a new game.", type: .debug)

            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Game", in: managedContext)!
            let newGameMO = GameMO(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

            newGameMO.setValue(gameMO.id, forKey: "id")
            newGameMO.setValue(gameMO.conferencesNames, forKeyPath: "conferencesNames")
            newGameMO.setValue(gameMO.confidence, forKeyPath: "confidence")
            newGameMO.setValue(gameMO.contestantsNames, forKeyPath: "contestantsNames")
            newGameMO.setValue(gameMO.winnerName, forKeyPath: "winnerName")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save new game to CoreData. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    }
```

```swift
public func loadGames() {

        os_log("loadGames() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<GameMO>(entityName: "GameMO")

        do {
            var gamesMO = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            os_log("Loading %d games", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, gamesMO.count)
            if gamesMO.count == 0 {
                guard let game1 = GameMO.newGameMO(id: UUID().uuidString, contestants: ["Elon", "NC A&T"], winner: "Elon", confidence: 65, conferences: [.caa], week: 0),
                    let game2 = GameMO.newGameMO(id: UUID().uuidString, contestants: ["James Madison", "Towson"], winner: "James Madison", confidence: 85, conferences: [.caa], week: 0),
                    let game3 = GameMO.newGameMO(id: UUID().uuidString, contestants: ["Samford", "Youngstown State"], winner: "Samford", confidence: 75, conferences: [.mvfc], week: 0),
                    let game4 = GameMO.newGameMO(id: UUID().uuidString, contestants: ["Elon", "The Citadel"], winner: "Elon", confidence: 60, conferences: [.caa, .southern], week: 1),
                    let game5 = GameMO.newGameMO(id: UUID().uuidString, contestants: ["Elon", "Richmond"], winner: "Elon", confidence: 80, conferences: [.caa], week: 2) else {
                        os_log("Could not create stub games in DataModelManager.loadGames()", type: .default)
                        return
                }
                gamesMO = [game1, game2, game3, game4, game5]
                os_log("Needed to load games for the first time", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            }
            self.allGames = gamesMO.map { (gameMO) -> Game in
                if let game = Game(fromGameMO: gameMO) {
                    return game
                } else {
                    return Game()
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch games. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
```

```swift
public static func newGameMO(fromGame game: Game) -> GameMO? {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return nil
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let gameMO = GameMO(context: managedContext)
        gameMO.id = game.id
        guard let teamName1 = game.contestants.first?.name, let teamName2 = game.contestants.last?.name else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap team names in GameMO.newGameMO(fromGame:)", type: .debug)
            return nil
        }
        gameMO.contestantsNames = [teamName1, teamName2]
        gameMO.confidence = game.confidence
        guard let conferenceName1 = game.contestants.first?.conferenceName, let conferenceName2 = game.contestants.last?.conferenceName else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap conference names in GameMO.newGameMO(fromGame:)", type: .debug)
            return nil
        }
        gameMO.conferencesNames = [conferenceName1, conferenceName2]
        gameMO.week = game.week
        gameMO.winnerName = game.winner.name

        return gameMO

    }
```

Comment: It looks like a new `GameMO` is created in `winnerChanged` and the same `GameMO` is fetched and updated in `saveOrCreateGameMO`. `NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", gameMO.id)` will fetch `gameMO`. Is `id` supposed to be uniqueue? The `newGameMO` created in `saveOrCreateGameMO` has the same `id` as `gameMO`.

Comment: So I create a new `GameMO` object in `winnerChanged`, and I pass it to the `saveOrCreateGame` method. Then I use the `NSPredicate` to get the `GameMO` object from CoreData that corresponds to that game `id`. Then I update the values for the properties of the Entity `GameMO` that's in CoreData and then `save`. I'm under the impression that this is the right way to do it. Is there something I'm missing? How is something getting saved doubly?

Comment: In `saveOrCreateGameMO` `gameMO` and `objectUpdate` are the same object. Instead of `fetch` you can do `objectUpdate = gameMO`. Example: the new `GameMO` in `winnerChanged` has `id` `123`. In `saveOrCreateGameMO` the `GameMO` with id `123` is fetched. This is the `GameMO` from `winnerChanged`.

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying is to just set `objectUpdate = gameMO`, and then `managedContext.save()`, and that will do it? That doesn't make sense. Also, why would the `NSPredicate` be returning a `gameMO` object every time, even when there isn't anything in the database (when the app first is installed)? `"Could not fetch game from CoreData. Saving it as a new game."` never gets shown in the logs.

Comment: What does `let gameMO = GameMO.newGameMO(fromGame: game)` in `winnerChanged` do?

Comment: It just takes a Game object, which has analogous variables to GameMO but in forms like team: Team instead of teamName: String, and transforms a Game object into a corresponding GameMO object

Comment: I added the code for newGameMO(fromGame:) into the question :)

Comment: So `newGameMO` adds a `GameMO` and this `GameMO` is fetched in `saveOrCreateGameMO`.